# Substring Ampscript extracting url within quotes

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, html, substring

We have a use case where we’re pulling in a url from Salesforce CRM which contains the entire A tag.  We’re looking to use Substring but can’t pull in the end of the URL before the quote.

- “” target=” won’t work,
- " target=" produces a quote at the end
- We’ve tried single quotes: ‘ “ target= “ ‘ with no luck.

Any ideas on how to extract the url below between the quotes to render in a call to action button in an email?

```
Request__c:Site_URL__c = <a href=”https://mycervello.com/?requestid=a0Y2i000003Upy0BBB&signature=%2HH2RWnDntoo3CmmyAySPy1qNvwoiTuTrubI8ovMv7aU%2D” target="_blank">Click here for the form</a>
```

Ampscript:

```ampscript
SET @emailLinklong= [Request__c:Site_URL__c]
SET @DP_StringBegin = " target="
SET @emailLink = Substring(@emailLinklong,10,Subtract(IndexOf(@emailLinklong,@DP_StringBegin),1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of hacky, but should work if the input matches the syntax of your example:

```ampscript
SET @emailLinklong= [Request__c:Site_URL__c]
SET @rowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@emailLinklong, "”")
SET @row = Row(@rowSet, 2)
SET @emailLink = Field(@row, 1)
```

How does this work?

`BuildRowsetFromString()` breaks your string into 3 different parts delimited by the `”` character

```
Row Number  |  RowSet
------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1       |  <a href=
    2       |  https://mycervello.com/?requestid=a0Y2i000003Upy0BBB&signature=%2HH2RWnDntoo3CmmyAySPy1qNvwoiTuTrubI8ovMv7aU%2D
    3       |  target="_blank">Click here for the form</a>
```

The resulting data is of the rowset data type, so you need to select the second row by using the `Row()` function and then pull it's contents with `Field` (this is not a rowset with multiple named fields, so using 1 as the parameter gets you the value you need).

Comment: Thank you Rafal, after experimenting by rendering the variable we were able to use the code and change the 1 to an 11 at the end, the quote wasn't the issue after all - sorry for not testing fully before posting:

SET @emailLink = Substring(@emailLinklong,10,Subtract(IndexOf(@emailLinklong,@DP_StringBegin),11))

We are capturing your suggestion for future use as we'll probably have a use case that will work, very cool design.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -2):

The replace function could work.

```ampscript
var @Link
SET @Link = replace(@emailLink, "” target=","")
```

https://ampscript.guide/replace/